# PhantomJS arguments.js example UTF-8 not working

Tags: linux, utf-8, debian, phantomjs

NOTE : This might be related to the question I already asked [Highcharts export server special characters replaced with question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346760/highcharts-export-server-special-characters-replaced-with-question-mark).

The PhantomJS [`arguments.js` example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/arguments.js) returns the parameters you give.

Example :

```
phantomjs arguments.js a b c
```

Returns :

```
0: arguments.js
1: a
2: b
3: c
```

On Mac OS X with PhantomJS 1.9.0 installed, I have no problem returning arguments with special characters. But on the remote server I'm working with (Linux Debian 6), it does not work as expected :

```
phantomjs arguments.js à é €
```

Which returns (as expected) the following on Mac OS X :

```
0: arguments.js
1: à
2: é
3: €
```

What I get on Linux Debian 6:

```
0: arguments.js
1: Ã 
2: Ã©
3: â
```

I have checked [PhantomJS requirements](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) and FreeType and Fontconfig are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had to configure the default encoding of the terminal (in my case `en_US.UTF-8` instead of `en_US`) and my problem was gone.

Here is [How to set up a clean UTF-8 environment in Linux](http://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment).